# Am I allowed to threaten to detonate a bomb when a group of people are illegally threatening my life in public?

Tags: united-states, self-defense

You are eating in a public restaurant. A group of people suddenly take out their guns and point them at you. You have a gun on you but you don't want to use it because you are afraid of getting shot while pulling it out. Instead you tell them you have placed a bomb on you (you do not), and you will detonate it (you cannot) if they get closer.

Is this legal? What is the most optimal strategy to execute in this situation?

Comment: I think the word you want is "detonate".  And you should look up *defense of necessity*.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. I'll check.

Comment: That's a highly unlikely and rather outlandish scenario. Why do you care ?

Comment: Praying seems to be the optimal strategy.

Comment: This is such an outlandish scenario. Please send me a link to the movie once it's finished.

Comment: @user253751 Star Wars VI?

Answer (score -1):

In Washington, it looks like it would be legal. As stated in [RCW 9a.16.020](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.16.020),

> The use, attempt, or offer to use force upon or toward the person of
> another is not unlawful in the following cases:...
>
> (3) Whenever used by a party about to be injured, or by another
> lawfully aiding him or her, in preventing or attempting to prevent an
> offense against his or her person, or a malicious trespass, or other
> malicious interference with real or personal property lawfully in his
> or her possession, in case the force is not more than is necessary;

Comment: The "force is not more than is necessary" part may preclude the OP's suggestion. The bomb would surely be a threat to more than just the aggressor and would do a lot more than just stop them.

Comment: The 'force' in this case would be the threat to detonate a **non-existing bomb**. It would probably be judged differently if the bomb existed. It would be up to a judge to make a final determination.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Likely a jury and not a judge would make that call.

Comment: @DM Wouldn't this process be started by a prosecuter making an application to a judge?

Comment: @MarkJohnson I suppose a judge might initially make a ruling on whether there's probable cause to issue an arrest warrant, but seeing as how self-defense is usually an affirmative defense, they almost certainly would issue it. And of course that would not be a "final" determination.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Although, come to think of it, felony indictments are usually issued by grand juries, aren't they?

Comment: @DM Sorry, I am more firm with civil code than with common law. In this case, where no deaths occurred (no bomb), a decision would have to be made whether to presue the matter further or not.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The statute in question seems to draw no difference between a "threat of force you can actually follow through on" and a "threat of force you cannot actually follow through on, but nobody knows that".  There's a threat of force.  What is that threat and force?  To detonate a bomb.  That you were bluffing to diffuse imminent lawlessness seems more likely to be something the jury might construe in your favor, so the prosecutor might decide it's not worth it to bring a charge, but that's a practical determination rather than a legal one.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy But the protection of ones own life or that of another may be taken as a higher priority.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The bomb threat very specifically endangers not only your own life but that of many others; almost surely at least as many are threatened by a bomb in an enclosed space as they are by some people with guns. Only the OP knows they're lying; everyone else may reasonably suppose there's a suicide bomber in their midst, and will respond in accordance to that (which may include a panic, which may result in the original threats firing their weapons at everyone, etc.) Threaten 20 bystanders to save one? Such a (threat of) force is well beyond necessary.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy A civilian, who is not trained for such a death threating situation, is not assumed to be rational in such a situation where such a self defense is needed. If it the only option available, then it may be deemed as necessary.

Comment: Threaten 20 bystanders. One of them might be armed and decide it’s best to shoot you without warning (an it’s a situation where you wouldn’t give a warning). I can very much see a claim of self defence to succeed.

Comment: The “it’s not unlawful” doesn’t apply because excessive force was threatened. So what remains is an unlawful threat to explode a bomb, with no means to actually do it.

Comment: As a general rule, the threat of use of lethal force always implies you can use said lethal force regardless of whether you can use.  For example, assault with a deadly weapon occurs when you point a gun at a person regardless of whether the gun is loaded, or operable, or just a toy with the orange safety cap removed, or in fact a hose nozzle held under your coat.   So whether or not you have a bomb, threatening to detonate a bomb implies that you will follow through on that threat regardless of the fact that you cannot.+

Comment: I knew someone who worked in a high school which had a few bomb threats called in from time to time.   The schools were always evacuated and thouroghly searched and found to not have any explosive device in the building... and the offender was always arrested for making the threat.